# Linear independence of a set of $4$ polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Determine whether the next set of vectors $$\{x^2-1, 2x-3, x^2+1, 4x\}$$ is a linearly independent or a non linearly independent subset of $P$ (the vector space of polynomials).

It was today in my final exams of linear algebra. I tried to resolve it with Gauss-Jordan, and given that it hasn't solution, I concluded that it was linearly dependent. Also, I think that there are a theorem to figure it out.

Comment: $6=1\cdot 4x-2\cdot(2x-3)$ but also $6=3\cdot(x^2+1)-3\cdot(x^2-1)$. Can you see a linear dependency relation here?

Comment: As Jyrki Lahtonen has pointed out, $1(4x)-2(2x-3)=3(x^2+1)-3(x^2-1)$ so $3(x^2-1)-2(2x-3)-3(x^2+1)+(4x)=0$. There is a linear combination of the set which equals 0 or $c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3 + c_4 v_4 = 0$. Therefore with simple algebra it is possible to represent any of the vectors as a linear combination of the other. The requirement for a vector to be Independent is that it "isn't related to the others". So it appears you were correct.

Comment: Also, you do have a system of linear equations $c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3 + c_4 v_4 = 0$ if the basis is expressed in terms of a standard basis. You can solve it using Gauss-Jordan elimination as you used. This is probably the most routine way to do so, where it is applicable a computer could do it or calculator.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** These four polynomials are all contained in the vector space $P_2 := \langle 1, x, x^2 \rangle$ of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$. What is the dimension of $P_2$?

Answer (score 4):

A set of vectors $\{v_k\}$ in a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ are linearly independent whenever we can find $c_k \in F$ not all zero such that $\displaystyle \sum_k c_kv_k = 0$.

In this case, consider $c_1(x^2 - 1) + c_2(2x-3) + c_3(x^2 + 1) + c_4(4x)$.   Combine like terms and see if you can choose a set of $c_k \in \mathbb{R}$ (not all zero) for which this sum equals the zero polynomial.  If you can, then the polynomials are not linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

If a set is dependent, then a certain vector or vectors can be expressed as linear combination of previous vectors in the set.
Just check if you can express last $3$ polynomials as a linear combination of previous polynomials.
For an example, for the third polynomial: $$x^2+1=\alpha (x^2-1) + \beta (2x-3)$$
If such $\alpha$ and $\beta$ exist, your set is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You have four polynomials that are elements of the vector space spanned by the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$. So this space has dimension $3$ and we canno have four linearly independent vectors in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right: they are linearly dependent.

if we give 4 coefficients $a, b, c, d$ and let, $$a(x^2-1)+b(2x-3)+c(x^2+1)+d(4x)=0$$

we can get,

for term $x^2$, $a+c=0$

for term $x$, $2b+4d=0$

for const term, $-a-3b+c=0$

solve it, we get $$c=\frac32b$$ $$a=-\frac32b$$ $$d=-\frac12b$$

And if you use Travis hint, it would be just writing down "linear dependent" as your answer.